# How to make Bootstrap Radio Buttons which become darker after being selected

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, button

In plain HTML radio buttons are very convenient to see which button was selected (it stays selected even after you move a cursor away). How to make the same style using Bootstrap (that is to make selected buttons stay darker after moving a cursor away)? Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Button example</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" scr="./scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">


        <div class="form-group" name="option6" style="text-align: center;">
            <div class="btn-group-vertical" data-toggle="buttons">

                <label class="btn btn-primary">
                    <input type="radio" name="option6" checked="checked" value="have">have<br>
                </label>

                <label class="btn btn-primary">
                    <input type="radio" name="option6" value="is having">is having<br>
                </label>
            </div>          
        </div>

    </div>        

    </body>

</html>
```

But this buttons stay unselected after I move a cursor away.

Comment: You can add **class** to radio buttons when they are checked 
   `.darker {
         box-shadow:1px 2px 3px; 
     }`

Using javscript

Answer (score 0):

Not seeing anything wrong with your code... works here [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tz6k4j5s/)

Make sure that both JS load and the CSS.

(Maybe `./styles/bootstrap.min.css` should be `css/bootstrap.min.css`?)

Comment: I just named the folder with my Bootstrap css as "styles". Yeah, lpretty strange. It works in JSFiddle but not in my browser.

Comment: Chrome console gives me Error Message: "Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's Javascript requires jQuery (...)". What can I do wiht that?

Comment: I deployed this code as a web-site http://autoenglishtest.esy.es/index.html  But it does not work the way I need. However it is fine in JSFiddle.